# Prevent taking screenshots by any application using Java

Tags: java, swing, javafx

How can I prevent taking screenshots by any application using Java?
Some applications takes screenshots every 5-10 mins, and I want that all these screenshots to be black or something similar.

Comment: You don't. You can't. Good luck!

Comment: Can I prevent for specific application?

Comment: Was "can't" unclear?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can't it somehow prevented? Some DRM protected media for example makes screenshots only black.

Comment: Java runs on a virtual machine. That virtual machine would have to implement DRM protection for that capability to be available for you to use. It does not. There is nothing in Java to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As [Frisch commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644536/prevent-taking-screenshots-by-any-application-using-java#comment116065073_65644536), Java apps runs in a virtual machine. No [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) I know of has implemented [DRM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) to suppress screen-shots.

And the issue is moot. Most everybody nowadays carries a phone in their pocket or purse. Those phones are equipped with a high-resolution camera capable of taking digital images of any screen.

Comment: Plus one for mentioning the phone. I had an artist friend who scoffed at 'prevent screen shots' years ago. *"I could just draw it!"*

Comment: @AndrewThompson We thought of everything but the damn artists!